# Pushing a SharedPreference File before installing in android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I need to set some configurations for my android application, like the server IP and Port, which the application should use to communicate. How can I add do it?

I thought of using sharedpreferences. How can I push a sharedpreference file with configurations, before even installing the app.

P.S. I don't want to hardcode the IP and PORT in the code base.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: "How can I push a sharedpreference file with configurations, before even installing the app." -- that is not an option, sorry. Use default values in your preference XML.

Comment: @CommonsWare. Thanks for the reply. How about for enterprise applications. Where we do have access to all the devices. Can we not push an XML file onto device from which it can be used by the application?

Comment: Possibly, but unless your MDM system can push files to [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/06/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), you cannot put an XML file in the spot where saved preference data goes. You are welcome to have your MDM system push a file to [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), but then your app will need to read that in and decide whether the values in that file need to be reflected in the saved preference values or not.

Answer (score 0):

You CAN NOT push anything before installing. But you can store necessary data in SharedPreferences and retrieve whenever you want. To write/read String data to/from SharedPreferences;

```
private static final String SHARED_PREFS = "sharedPrefYourApp";
private static final String TEXT = "IP/PORT";
private static final String KEY = "IP_PORT_KEY";

public static void saveData(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = 
    context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(KEY, TEXT);
    editor.apply();
}

public static String loadData(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = 
    context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
    String text = sharedPreferences.getString(KEY, "");
    return text;
}
```

Comment: How about for enterprise applications. Where we do have access to all the devices. Can we not push an XML file onto device from which it can be used by the application?@dcanbatman

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. An alternate would be to ship the app with a json config file - put that in the assets folder

And read the contents of the file to prefill values you need.

```
try {             
InputStream inputStream = mContext.getAssets().open(mContext.getPackageName() + ".json");                  
int size = inputStream.available();     
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];          
        if (inputStream.read(buffer) != size) {     
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();     
        }     
        inputStream.close();          
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(new String(buffer, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));     
        server_ip = jsonObject.getString("server_ip");
        server_port = jsonObject.getString("server_port");     
    } catch (Exception e) {     
        e.printStackTrace();     
    }     
}
```

I would personally put that code in a class that extends Application, so it is called only once.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have to create a json file and make it as a part of application. But, What if there are different configuration files for different devices. I would like to push some configuration while installing. I do have access to device, while installing the application as it is an enterprise application.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be using something like Firebase Remote Config and then providing the app with configurations dynamically. Think of this approach as the app connecting to a static place; downloads configurations securely and then reacts to those configurations and connects to the end services securely.

If you are trying to make this secure, I would recommend using the Android keychain instead of SharedPreferences - I barely use SharedPreferences (although that's a preference or it depends on security and use case needs).

Answer (score -1):

This is now available in Android via "Managed Configurations"

https://developer.android.com/work/managed-configurations

Comment: That doesn't fulfill his use case and he is most likely also not developing an app for enterprise.